# Error CORS policy al leer un archivo json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo json, el cual es un simple array que tiene lo siguiente:

```
[
{
    "CodigoInterno": "ABCDE123",
    "DetallePregunta": "¿Es una preunta?",
    "TipoPreguntaRespuesta": "OMUR",
    "MultiValuado": false
},
{
    "CodigoInterno": "ABCDE123",
    "DetallePregunta": "¿Es una preunta?",
    "TipoPreguntaRespuesta": "TEXT",
    "MultiValuado": false
},
{
    "CodigoInterno": "ABCDE123",
    "DetallePregunta": "¿Es una preunta?",
    "TipoPreguntaRespuesta": "TEXT",
    "MultiValuado": false
},
{
    "CodigoInterno": "ABCDE123",
    "DetallePregunta": "¿Es una preunta?",
    "TipoPreguntaRespuesta": "TEXT",
    "MultiValuado": false
}
]
```

El problema que al leer la consola me genera el siguiente error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/SUPER/Desktop/pruebas%20estilos/rancho/preguntas.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

El codigo que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $.getJSON("./preguntas.json", function (datos) {
             console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

La cuestión no entiendo el pro que me esta saliendo este error, ya que tengo entendio que las CORS policy aplican para consultas a apis, alguien puede ayudarme en esto

Comment: El archivo JSON, estara en un servidor en un futuro o intentas leerlo de local? Si es local, estas usando node?

Comment: El mensaje de error lo dice todo. Aparentemente, estas accediendo a la página que ejecuta esta secuencia de comandos con un esquema de protocolo diferente a los varios admitidos para solicitudes de origen cruzado. Esto ocurre comúnmente si, por ejemplo, ejecuta un archivo local en su navegador a través del protocolo file: // y trata de acceder a alguna URL en Internet en la llamada que haces $.getJSON

Answer (score 1):

Es un error provocado por políticas de seguridad del browser. Te será imposible ejecutar requests para acceder a archivos JSON locales. En su lugar estos archivos deben ser servidos a través de algún servidor web o que tu programa javascript sea ejecutado en nodejs.

Si este no es tu caso, siempre podrás convertir tu json a javascript y cargar dinámicamente tu json. Es un truco pero sirve.

```
var dataXJSON = `{"p":"value"}`;
var dataX = JSON.parse(dataXJSON);
```

Luego como última opción algunos navegadores permiten desactivar esta política de seguridad con algún parámetro/flag de inicio del programa, por ejemplo en Chrome es : 
`--allow-file-access-from-files`.

Answer (score 0):

La validacion CORS que hacen los navegadores no son exclusivas del consumo de APIS, aplican siempre que se consuma un recurso por fuera del dominio actual, aunque este no es tu caso, el error ocurre por que estas cargando el html directamente desde disco y no desde un servidor, esto a su vez hace que el archivo json se trate de cargar desde el disco, por cuestiones de seguridad esto no esta permitido en el navegador que estas utilizando.

Para poder resolver el tema sugiero que utilices un servidor web local, para no complicarte la vida sugiero que en chrome bajes algún plugin como por ej: **[Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb)**, solo debes informar cual es la carpeta que contiene tu archivo html (y otros recursos como el .json) y un numero de puerto, hecho esto podras ejecutar tu pagina desde http://localhost:[puerto]/[nombrePagina].html